# Improving Merge Performance with Change Data Capture and Hash

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, merge, dimensional-modeling

Today I'm trying to tune the performance of an audit database. I have a legal reason for tracking changes to rows, and I've implemented a set of tables using the System Versioned tables method in SQL Server 2016.

My overall process lands "RAW" data into an initial table from a source system. From here, I then have a MERGE process that takes data from the RAW table and compares every column in the RAW table to what exists in the audit-able system versioned staging table and decides what has changed. System row versioning then tells me what has changed and what hasn't.

The trouble with this approach is that my tables are very wide. Some of them have 400 columns or more. Even tables that have 450,000 records take SQL server about 17 minutes to perform a MERGE operation. It's really slowing down the performance of our solution and it seems it would help things greatly if we could speed it up. We presently have hundreds of tables we need to do this for.

At the moment both the RAW and STAGE tables are indexed on an ID column.

I've read in several places that we might consider using a CHECKSUM or HASHBYTES function to record a value in the RAW extract. (What would you call this? GUID? UUID? Hash?). We'd then compare the calculated value to what exists in the STAGE table. But here's the rub: There are often quite a few NULL values across many columns. It's been suggested that we cast all the column types to be the same (nvarchar(max))?, and NULL values seem to cause the entire computation of the checksum to fall flat. So I'm also coding lots of ISNULL(,'UNKNOWN') statements into my code too.

So - Are there better methods for improving the performance of the merge here? I thought that I could use a row updated timestamp column as a single value to compare instead of the checksum, but I am not certain that that would pass legal muster/scrutiny. Legal is concerned that rows may be edited outside of an interface and the column wouldn't always be updated. I've seen approaches with developers using a concatenate function (shown below) to combine many column values together. This seems code intensive and expensive to compute / cast columns too.

So my questions are:

- Given the situational reality, can I improve MERGE performance in any way here?
- Should I use a checksum, or hashbytes, and why?
- Which hashbytes method makes the most sense here? (I'm only comparing one RAW row to another STAGE row based on an ID match right)?
- Did I miss something with functions that might make this comparison faster or easier in the reading 
  I have done? It seems odd there aren't better functions besides CONCAT available to do this in SQL Server.
- I wrote the below code to show some of the ideas I am considering. Is there something better than what I wrote below?

  ```
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS MyTable;

  CREATE TABLE MyTable
      (C1 VARCHAR(10),
       C2 VARCHAR(10),
       C3 VARCHAR(10)
       );

  INSERT INTO MyTable
      (C1,C2,C3)
  VALUES
      (NULL,NULL,NULL),
      (NULL,NULL,3),
      (NULL,2,3),
      (1,2,3);


  SELECT
      HASHBYTES('SHA2_256',
      CONCAT(C1,'-',
             C2,'-',
             C3)) AS HashbytesValueCastWithNoNullCheck,


      HASHBYTES('SHA2_256',
      CONCAT(CAST(C1 as varchar(max)),'-',
             CAST(C2 as varchar(max)),'-',
             CAST(C3 as varchar(max)))) AS HashbytesValueCastWithNoNullCheck,


      HASHBYTES('SHA2_256',
      CONCAT(ISNULL(CAST(C1 as varchar(max)),'UNKNOWN'),'-',
             ISNULL(CAST(C2 as varchar(max)),'UNKNOWN'),'-',
             ISNULL(CAST(C3 as varchar(max)),'UNKNOWN'))) AS HashbytesValueWithCastWithNullCheck,
      CONCAT(ISNULL(CAST(C1 as varchar(max)),'UNKNOWN'),'-',
             ISNULL(CAST(C2 as varchar(max)),'UNKNOWN'),'-',
             ISNULL(CAST(C3 as varchar(max)),'UNKNOWN')) AS StringValue,
      CONCAT(C1,'-',C2,'-',C3) AS ConcatString,
      C1,
      C2,
      C3
  FROM
      MyTable;

  '''
  ```

Comment: Hashbytes is the way I've done it (note that even SHA2_256 has a chance of collision, so make sure it passes legal, not just functional needs).  Is there any room for using a tool like Redgate's DataCompare? Comparison tools probably use the same underlying functions, but I've seen it perform very quickly so maybe they have additional algorithms.  Also, you need to add a delimiter between your terms, otherwise 'Jo Nethen' = 'Jon Ethen'.

Answer (score 2):

> Given the situational reality, can I improve MERGE performance in any way here?

You should test, but storing a hash for every row, computing the hash for the new rows, and comparing based on the (key,hash) should be cheaper than comparing every column.

> Should I use a checksum, or hashbytes, and why?

HASHBYTES has a much lower probability of missing a change.  Roughly, with CHECKSUM you'll probably eventually miss a change or two, with HASHBYTES you probably won't ever miss a change.  See remarks here: [BINARY_CHECKSUM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/binary-checksum-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks).

> Did I miss something with functions that might make this comparison faster or easier in the reading I have done?

No. There's no special way to compare multiple columns.

> Is there something better than what I wrote below?

You definitely should replace nulls, else a row `(1,null,'A')` and `(1,'A',null)` would get the same hash.  And you should replace nulls, and delimit, with something that won't appear as a value in any column.  And if you have Unicode text, converting to varchar may erase some changes, so it's safer to use nvarchar.  eg:

```
HASHBYTES('SHA2_256',
    CONCAT(ISNULL(CAST(C1 as nvarchar(max)),N'~'),N'|',
           ISNULL(CAST(C2 as nvarchar(max)),N'~'),N'|',
           ISNULL(CAST(C3 as nvarchar(max)),N'~'))) AS HashbytesValueWithCastWithNullCheck
```

JSON in SQL Server is very fast.  So you might try a pattern like:

```
select t.Id, z.RowJSON, hashbytes('SHA2_256', RowJSON) RowHash
from SomeTable t
cross apply (select t.* for json path) z(RowJSON)
```

Comment: As a thought, what do you think about combining `binary_checksum()` and `hashbytes()` to avoid the `isnull()` stuff? POC as `select *, HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', concat(checksum(a, b, c), a, b, c))
from (values (1, 'A', null), (1, null, 'A')) as x(a, b, c);`

Comment: That's clever, but I see no way to estimate the probability of a collision.  See answer update for an alternative.